# Why do we say "he made me eat it" but "he allowed me TO eat it"?

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitive

Why does the choice of the first verb "made" vs. "allowed" change the tense of the second verb "eat" vs "to eat"?
Using the opposite tense in either case sounds completely wrong.  e.g. I'd never say "he made me **to** eat it" or "he allowed me eat it"
Similarly "make him eat it" vs. "force him **to** eat it"

Is it just "made/make" that is special? I can't think of any other verb that doesn't make the following verb take the infinitive tense (sorry for my bad terminology there). Or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137389/discussion-on-question-by-automatedmike-why-do-we-say-he-made-me-eat-it-but-h).

Comment: **Do not answer in comments.** If you have an answer, even if you consider it incomplete, use the answer box.

Answer (score 2):

What comes after *make* is still an infinitive; it's just a *bare* infinitive, one not marked by *to.* There are other verbs like this, even ignoring auxiliaries:

1. He **let** me do it.
2. He **helped** me do it.
3. He **saw** me do it.
4. He **had** me do it.

My source for this is Huddleston & Pullum (2002), p. 1244. There isn't a precise rule for which verbs work this way, though many verbs related to perception can follow this pattern, e.g. *see, hear, watch, notice.*

Modal auxiliary verbs also work this way (as in "He *can* do it"), though they have a number of other unusual properties.

Comment: There **are** precise rules for each one of those; what there isn't is a single rule that covers all of them and no others. There is also no list of verbs that "work this way" because "this way" is not defined. The question is ill-formed and makes a number of incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Auxiliary verbs work this way? * *He is walk his dog* / * *He has walk his dog*

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Corrected. I meant only modal auxiliary verbs.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Not all verbs that express modality are auxiliaries. Compare: "He ought to do it." (Some speakers will allow "Oughtn't he (to) do it?" but they seem to be in the minority.)

Answer (score 2):

This by no means unusual.
[You should look up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb) ****catenative* verbs.*** These are primary verbs that can "chain" to another  second verb(s) in the form of the "bare" infinitive, "to" infinitive, or gerund.

These are verb patterns, and depend on common usage, and not some rigid rule.

Also, some of the verbs mentioned in your post could be considered "causative" verbs.

Some grammars disagree about what actually constitutes a causative verb: some grammars  only allow ***make, get***, and ***have***...while others consider ***help***, ***let*** and ***allow*** to follow the same **verb patterns**

To confuse matters even more difficult , we also have *passive-causative* constructions.

My suggestion is that you study ***catenative verb structures***. There are no well-defined rules for classification into groups; in fact, verbs such as *help* can take 2 different verbs forms for the second main verb.

Comment: Could you name grammarians who don't classify _help_, _let_, or _allow_ as a causative verb? More importantly, what's their reasoning for not classifying them as a causative verb?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the choice of first verb *made* vs. *allowed* change the tense of the second verb *eat* vs *to eat*?

It doesn't. The main, matrix verb in the main clause is tensed -- both *made* and *allowed* are past tense -- but those are the only tensed verbs in the sentence. Both *make* and *allow* take infinitive complement clauses, but infinitives are not a verb tense; they're a verb **form**, but not a tense. English only has present and past tenses, but it has other verb forms, like *eaten* and *eating*; these aren't tenses, either.

Moreover,

- **Infinitives Do Not Have Tense**

That's why they were named *infinitives* -- **finite** verbs have tenses, **non-finite** verb forms do not. And infinitives never do. OK? So no tenses have been changed in the production of these sentences.

Now, why are there infinitives? Well, many if not most main verbs can have objects (or displaced subjects) that are clauses -- they have a verb, and that verb may be tensed or not, depending on what the main verb is. Quite often, the complement clause is an infinitive clause, and that may have the complementizer *to* to mark the infinitive. Mostly they do. But there are a small number of "small verbs" -- common, confusing, irregular, and idiomatic, on their way to becoming auxiliary verbs themselves -- that have special properties: sense verbs like *see* and *hear*, inchoative, causatives, emotional predicates, etc. These appear often in idiomatic constructions, and may appear without *to*.

- *She saw him leave. She let him leave. She had him mow her lawn.*

Each of these contains two clauses, and the second clause consists of the pronoun and the infinitive verb  phrase; that clause is the direct object of *saw, let, had*, all of which are tensed. The infinitive is not tensed.

Comment: In your three examples, the object is just "him". The subordinate clause consists of just "leave", "leave" and "mow her lawn". Additionally, in the second, "him" is a raised object. Note that in the plain-complex construction (i.e. with an infinitival subordinate clause) the intervening NP always belongs syntactically in the matrix.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that you prefer it when I use your favorite terminology. So, if I need to know how CGEL would describe something, I'll ask.

Comment: Even websites aimed at learners and ESL's acknowledge that it's just the intervening NP that is the object. See here: [link](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-catenative-complex.php) They say "the object of the catenative verb effectively functions as the subject of the second verb, which we understand to mean it functions as the _semantic_ subject of the subordinate clause.

Comment: @BillJ Why did you say "Additionally, in the second, "him" is a raised object", when "him" in all three examples are raised objects?